# How to export Google sheet as JSON in specific order

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get a sheet from Google is a specific order. The json comes A,B,C,D,E,F... and  I want it K,J,C,D,E,F,M. How is this possible?
Here is the code I am using

```
var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var numCols = rows.getNumColumns();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var output = "";
  output += "{\n";
  var header = values[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i > 1) output += " , \n";
    var row = values[i];
    output += "\""+row[0]+"\" : {";
    for (var a = 1;a<numCols;a++){
      if (a > 1) output += " , ";
         output += "\""+columnToLetter(a)+"\" : \""+row[a]+"\"";
    }
    output += "}";
  }
  output += "\n}";
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(output).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

Comment: If you know the order you want, store the index order in an `Array` (e.g. `const order = [10, 2, 0, 5, ...]`) and iterate that. Consider also building the output as an actual `Object`, and then using `JSON.stringify` to convert it to a string.

Comment: Thank you very much I tried it and it works fine. Also I am changing the output to what you suggested seems much easier.